# Why are object properties specified outside of constructor in java?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Why are object properties specified outside of constructor in java? Isn't it more convenient to specify properties inside of constructor?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because language design questions are best addressed to the designer of the language. A single, non-opinion answer is only available from them (if then).

Comment: I don't see how what you suggest would work as it breaks all the scoping rules, so the answer is likely to be no, not at all.  How would the compiler tell the difference between fields and local variables for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about visibility. Properties are declared outside of constructor, so they can be visible in the class. But they are initialized inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The properties declared outside the constructor become the `instance variables` of that class and they can have their own value for the object and can be used anywhere in the class.

The properties declared inside the constructor won't be the properties of the class they will be just the `local variables` that can be used inside that constructor only.

It is more about usability than convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about bean convention when class has default constructor and a set of triples: property, setter and getter.

This paradigm was invented years ago. Its advantage is in ability to initialize objects using kind of generic way via reflection. For example map XML tags or JSON properties to java bean properties dynamically.

But this is not the only design paradigm. You can set all data via constructor. Moreover in this case you can make you class *immutable* that gives you a lot of advantages in multithreaded environment.

But using constructor based initialization is not very convenient when class has a lot of properties. Especially if some of them have default values. 
Builder pattern can help to work this problem.

Please do not hesitate to ask more specific questions.